# AngularJS, How to call a function in component from Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Thanks in advance, Basically in app component a timer which should be start when I call from a directive, Please let me know how I can call? I tried some method but didn't helpful. I'm new in angular js Please guide me.Thanks Here is the Js File code.

```
var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);
app.directive('quiz', function (quizFactory) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope: {},     
    templateUrl: '/Home/Dashboard',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

              //Calling function cmpTimer(); in Component
        };
     }
    }
});
```

```
app.component('cmpTimer', {
    bindings: {
        cmpFrom: '<',
        cmpUnit: '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="timer">{{$ctrl.timeRemaining}}</div>',
    controller: function ($interval) {
        var vm = this, ONE_SECOND = 1000, timerInterval;

        function startTimer() {
            var END_TIME = vm.getEndTime();

            function update() {
                vm.timeRemaining = moment((moment(END_TIME) -       moment())).format("HH:mm:ss");
            }

            timerInterval = $interval(function () {
                if (moment() > moment(END_TIME)) return vm.stopTimer();

                update();
            }, ONE_SECOND);

            update();
        }

        vm.getEndTime = function () {
            return moment().add(vm.cmpFrom, vm.cmpUnit);
        }

        vm.stopTimer = function () {
            alert('Time\'s up!');

            vm.$onDestroy();
        }

        vm.$onDestroy = function () {
            $interval.cancel(timerInterval);
        }

        vm.$onInit = startTimer;
    }
});
```

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication).

Comment: Why use a directive for `quiz` and a component for `cmp-timer`? Why not make both of them components?